# Android - Remove element from RecyclerView throws ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating this app where I have one RecyclerView with some pictures. If the user wants to remove one of them he has too long press the picture and a gray transparent layout will be shown on the top of the picture with an "X" button to remove the picture. When the user press the "X" is shown a dialog asking for confirmation if he accepts then the picture is deleted. I don't understand why I'm receiving "ConcurrentModificationException" when I accept to delete the picture. The line marked is "return data.size();" on method "getItemCount()", and I'm not accessing "data" from any other side, I just can see that "getItemCount" is called many times. Notice that I removed unnecessary functions and members of the class.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<String> data;

public RecyclerViewAdAdapter(Context context, List<String> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = items;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_create_ad_item_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String imagePath = data.get(position);
    setImageBitmap(imagePath, holder.itemImage);
    holder.removeItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.confirm_remove_picture);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    removeItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

private void removeItem(int position) {
    data.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, data.size());
}

private void setImageBitmap(String item, ImageView imageView) {
    /***/
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView itemImage;
    RelativeLayout grayTopLayout;
    ImageView removeItemButton;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        grayTopLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grayTopLayout);
        removeItemButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.removeItemButton);

        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                switch (grayTopLayout.getVisibility()) {
                    case View.VISIBLE:
                        v.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);
                        grayTopLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                    case View.GONE:
                        RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                        params.width = itemImage.getWidth();
                        v.setLayoutParams(params);
                        v.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);
                        grayTopLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case View.INVISIBLE:
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough **notifyItemRemoved** method. Remove **notifyItemRangeChanged** your code should be like this

```
private void removeItem(int position) {
data.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

**EDIT**

Instead of using `List` use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) prevent

[**ConcurrentModificationException**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

Comment: @Ramin are you shoure nobody else access your array?

Comment: yeah, I saw, I'm looking for a way to convert List to CopyOnWriteArrayList without for loop

Comment: the problem get solved, on the constructor of CopyOnWriteArrayList it accepts a List, and no more ConcurrentModificationException, thank you very much